# git-bash -- Control-Z not working

Tags: git

I am trying to follow `git commit-tree` example in http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/plumbing using `git-bash`.

I am supposed to type a commit message after executing the command, then type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However as soon as I type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, the `git-bash` window closes!  I have tried it several times.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> (at the beginning of a line) instead but that has no effect.

How can I do this example in `git-bash`?

Comment: Looks like you type the ^Z to the git-bash as such, and that always closes a shell. Where do you type the commit message? Does an editor open up? Do you type it on stdin?

Answer (score 1):

i tried messing with stty settings for eol and eol2 and nothing worked.

finally switched to Git CMD and did the same command, typing ctrl-z.  the commit-tree worked there and i just switched back to bash for the rest.  nice curve ball in the last few pages of the course :)

Answer (score 0):

What system are you using?

On Unix, <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> is the default *suspend* character; it suspends the current process. You *must* type the eof character, by default <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> (at the beginning of a new line, ie. after <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).
You can query the current settings with `stty -a`. Look for `eof = ^d` and `susp = ^z`.

If you don't want to end the message with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you need to use *two* eof characters (<kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>) to signal end-of-file to the terminal.

Comment: As I said... git-bash... it is a Windows pseudo-shell